# Errback not being fired on unhandled exception within @inlineCallbacks-decorated function

Tags: python, twisted

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks


def fail():
  raise Exception()

@inlineCallbacks
def foo():
  yield reactor.callLater(5.0, fail)

def dump(*args, **kwargs):
  print 'dump', args, kwargs

d = foo()
d.addErrback(dump)

reactor.run()
```

Here we have a dummy function `foo()` which yields to a Deferred that will fire in 5 seconds. When it fires, an exception is thrown, which I would expect would be caught by the errback associated with my top-level Deferred object:

1. `foo()` is called and immediately returns a Deferred. We add an errback to it which just prints out its parameters.
2. After a few seconds, the reactor calls `fail()`.
3. `fail()` throws an exception.
4. The exception is "thrown" into the generator at the point it yielded. [Documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.inlineCallbacks.html):

> The generator will be sent the result of the Deferred with the 'send' method on generators, or if the result was a failure, 'throw'.

5. The exception is not caught inside the generator, so the Deferred for `foo()` should have its errback invoked:

> Your inlineCallbacks-enabled generator will return a Deferred object, which ... will fail with a failure object if your generator raises an unhandled exception

6. In invoking the errback, `dump()` should be called.

Instead:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled", line 19, in <module>
    reactor.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1192, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "untitled", line 6, in fail
    raise Exception()
exceptions.Exception:
```

To further test this, I tried (a) raising an exception directly within `foo()`, and (b) trying to catch the exception thrown by `fail()` inside `foo()`.

(a) works fine, and my errback is called.

(b) does not work, and results in the same issue:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def foo():
  try:
    yield reactor.callLater(5.0, fail)
  except Exception, e:
    print e
```

This is Twisted 15.1.0 and Python 2.7.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `deferLater` instead as this will return a `Deferred` like you desire.

```
from twisted.internet import task, defer, reactor

def fail(*args):
    raise Exception()

def error(*args):
    print(args)

def dump(*args, **kwargs):
    print('dump', args, kwargs)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def foo():
    d = task.deferLater(reactor, 1.0, fail)
    d.addErrback(error)
    yield d

D = foo()
D.addCallback(dump)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, `reactor.callLater` doesn't return a Deferred. You can get this to work with

```
def fail(_):
  raise Exception()

@inlineCallbacks
def foo():
  d = Deferred()
  d.addCallback(fail)
  reactor.callLater(1.0, d.callback, None)
  yield d
```